# How To Implement Binary Multiplication Using Emulated Logic Gates in Python?

Tags: python

This is similar to another question I posted today. I apologize for not merging them together in the first place. 0

I am in the process of creating a CPU simulator using Python. This project is not intended to be extremely accurate. Instead, it is meant to show the basic logic of a CPU, cache, RAM, ALU, etc.

I am struggling to implement a binary multiplication function using logic gates. Below is what I have so far:

These are the logic gates:

```
class ANDGate:
    def execute(a, b):
        result = ""
        for bit_a, bit_b in zip(a, b):
            result += '1' if bit_a == '1' and bit_b == '1' else '0'
        return result


class ORGate:
    def execute(a, b):
        result = ""
        for bit_a, bit_b in zip(a, b):
            result += '1' if bit_a == '1' or bit_b == '1' else '0'
        return result


class XORGate:
    def execute(a, b):
        result = ""
        for bit_a, bit_b in zip(a, b):
            result += '1' if (bit_a == '1' and bit_b == '0') or (bit_a == '0' and bit_b == '1') else '0'
        return result


class NOTGate:
    def execute(a):
        result = ""
        for bit_a in a:
            result += '0' if bit_a == '1' else '1'
        return result
```

And this is the multiplication method:

```
    def multiply(a, b):
        result = '0'

        # Convert binary strings to lists for easier manipulation
        a_list = list(a)
        b_list = list(b)

        # Initialize variables to hold intermediate results
        partial_results = []

        for bit_b in reversed(b_list):
            partial_result = ""
            carry = '0'

            for bit_a in reversed(a_list):
                # Perform XOR of individual bits
                sum_bit = XORGate.execute(bit_a, bit_b)
                
                # Perform AND of individual bits to get the carry
                carry_bit = ANDGate.execute(bit_a, bit_b)
                
                # XOR the carry with the sum_bit
                sum_bit = XORGate.execute(sum_bit, carry)
                
                # Update the carry for the next iteration
                carry = ORGate.execute(carry_bit, ANDGate.execute(bit_a, carry))

                partial_result = sum_bit + partial_result

            # Add the result of this iteration to the partial_results list
            partial_results.append(partial_result)

        # Sum the partial results to get the final result
        for partial in partial_results:
            result = bin(int(result, 2) + int(partial, 2))[2:]

        return result.lstrip('0') or '0'
```

The current output for 00000100 and 00000011 is 111111110 instead of 1100.

I also have this working add method that could be implemented somewhere, but I did not find it useful in this instance.

```
    def add(a, b):
        result = ""
        carry = '0'
        max_len = max(len(a), len(b))

        # Zero-pad the shorter operand
        a = a.zfill(max_len)
        b = b.zfill(max_len)

        for bit_a, bit_b in zip(reversed(a), reversed(b)):
            sum_bit = XORGate.execute(XORGate.execute(bit_a, bit_b), carry)
            carry = ORGate.execute(ANDGate.execute(bit_a, bit_b), ORGate.execute(ANDGate.execute(XORGate.execute(bit_a, bit_b), carry), ANDGate.execute(bit_a, carry)))
            result = sum_bit + result

        if carry == '1':
            result = carry + result

        return result
```

Could someone please provide me with the correct solution and point out where I went wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Aside, multiplication is usually handled by the compiler (even at an assembly level), of any optimisations can be made. Usually it involves combinations of bit shifts and add/subtract logic is used.  (Most) multiplication can be (and is) carried out by a combination of methods, not a simple opcode like `add`, for example.

Comment: Your methods are all missing the `self` parameter. If these are static methods, you need to use the `@staticmethod` decorator.

Comment: @s3dev They're emulating the hardware's ALU, not writing an interpreter.

Comment: @Barmar, good point on @staticmethod; however, that won't impact the answer, given the context of the setup.

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49482/how-to-multiply-using-gates for a diagram that shows how to multiply using logic gates. Translate that into code that uses your classes.

Comment: To do this in an OOP way, you could give your classes attributes that refer to the inputs and output. This would allow you to represent connected gates in a circuit.

Comment: Further to @Barmar comment, this [Wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier) shows a two-bit multiplier logic gate diagram in the ‘Example circuits’ section.

Comment: If you are interested simulating binary multiplication, you should construct a multiplier by connecting multiple gates together into a larger circuit, not simply using individual gates as part of a software implementation of multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with:

Addition Method:

```
class ALU:
    def add(a, b):
        result = ""
        carry = '0'
        max_len = max(len(a), len(b))

        # Zero-pad the shorter operand
        a = a.zfill(max_len)
        b = b.zfill(max_len)

        for bit_a, bit_b in zip(reversed(a), reversed(b)):
            sum_bit = XORGate.execute(XORGate.execute(bit_a, bit_b), carry)
            carry = ORGate.execute(ANDGate.execute(bit_a, bit_b), ANDGate.execute(XORGate.execute(bit_a, bit_b), carry))
            result = sum_bit + result

        if carry == '1':
            result = carry + result

        return ALU.remove_leading_zeros(result)
```

Multiplication Method:

```
    def multiply(a, b):
        result = '0'
        max_len = max(len(a), len(b))

        # Zero-pad the shorter operand
        a = a.zfill(max_len)
        b = b.zfill(max_len)

        for bit_b in reversed(b):
            if bit_b == '1':
                result = ALU.add(result, a)

            a = a + '0'  # Shift 'a' to the left

        return ALU.remove_leading_zeros(result)
```

And here is the remove_leading_zeros method:

```
    def remove_leading_zeros(binary_str):
        return binary_str.lstrip('0')
```